# OnItemClickListener does not work with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, onitemclick

I'm trying to add a clickable list to my first android app with Custom Adapter
all is fine but when i use

```
mItemList.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("error", "error here");   
        }
    });
```

but there is no response 
no toast
no errors despite the list showing good

Custom Adapter

```
 public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public Context context;
public ArrayList<ItemModel> items;
.....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View grid;
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null ) {
        grid = new View(context);
        grid = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
Button bt = (Button) grid.findViewById(R.id.btn_list);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/font1.otf");
 bt.setText(items.get(position).getTitle().toString());
 bt.setTypeface(tf);
}else{
    grid = (View) convertView;
}
return grid;
}
....
}
```

Comment: are you extending Activity or ListActivity?

Comment: simply try (new OnItemClickListener(){

Comment: its not the good approach new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener use new onItemClickListner....

Comment: Please show the code where you bind your data into listview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `Button`, `ImageButton`, `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` inside your item layout, add these properties to them:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```